# How do I turn off or remove Android Visual Layout Editor?

Tags: android, eclipse

The Visual Layout Editor for Android in Eclipse does a poor job at presenting layouts and just gets in the way too much.

How do I turn it off?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply click the XML tab and write the layouts that way. Every time you open a file that you closed in XML mode, it should open in it as well.

Comment: It should, but it doesn't always do it that way.